# React: Accessing an objects properties within an array that I have mapped

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, object

I'm trying to make my first real React app and am pulling information from a database, updating the state to set that info as an array, and then trying to access the properties of the objects in the array.

```
function App() {

  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);

  function fetchStudentInfo() {
    fetch('https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        const transformedStudentData = data.students.map(studentData => {
          return {
            imgURL: studentData.pic,
            fullName: `${studentData.firstName} ${studentData.lastName}`,
            email: studentData.email,
            company: studentData.company,
            skill: studentData.skill
          }
        });
        setStudents(transformedStudentData);
      });
  }

  fetchStudentInfo();

  return (
    <div> {console.log(students[0].fullName)}
      <h1>Student Assessments</h1>
    </div>
  )

}

export default App;
```

I know I shouldn't be console.logging the info I'm trying to get, but I'm not even sure how to use the console in React to find out how to access my variables. Anyway, I get "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fullName')" as an error and it fails.
I'm really trying to pass down the array as properties to be used in my components, but I've taken out code to try and simplify the problem for myself and this is where I've hit a wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first render your `students` state is an empty array because that's how you've initialised it. On that first render you can't access the first index (because the data hasn't been fetched, or the state updated), and you can't access a property of an element that doesn't exist yet.

So you need a condition in there that renders: 1) if `students.length` is zero return a loading message (for example) 2) otherwise [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) over the students array which you now know exists to produce a list of student names.

Here's a working example that uses [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) to add an array to state after three seconds simulating your API `fetch`. You should be using `useEffect` like this for your `fetch` (with an empty dependency array) instead of calling your function directly in the component.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const json = '[{ "fullName": "Bob" },{ "fullName": "Karen" },{ "fullName": "Rick" }]';

function mockApi() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(json), 3000);
  });
}

function Example({ data }) {

  const [ students, setStudents ] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    function getData() {
      mockApi()
        .then(json => JSON.parse(json))
        .then(data => setStudents(data));
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  // Initial log will be `[]`
  // Second log will be the updated state stringified
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(students));
  }, [students]);

  // No data, so return the loading message, or spinner
  if (!students.length) return <div>Loading: wait 3 seconds</div>

  // Data! `map` over it to produce the list
  return (
    <ul>
      {students.map(student => {
        return <li>{student.fullName}</li>;
      })}
    </ul>
  );

};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I suppose I should learn more about useEffect... Thank you, that solved my problem very simply.

Comment: No problem. `useEffect` basically looks for changes in state. If you pass in an empty dependency array it will run once when the component mounts. If you pass in states to that array the effect will run every time that state is updated.

Comment: I've added an additional effect to my answer to show you what I mean. When `students` is updated the effect handles the update and prints out the JSON of the state. @HarrySIV